# Rails-Mysql RDS Freeable memory dropping

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-rds, session-timeout

I've mentioned rails specifically in the question because it looks somewhat related to the application. In the production, we havn't specified `wait_timeout` parameter (don't kill me for this, I just figured out) and some heavy operations are going on these days. I see a regular drop of 10 MB or so on our production RDS. Though the Freeable memory is quite high but ultimately it will come down soon. On running `show full processlist;`, I saw many queries in sleep state whose time field shows a value as high as 7 to 10 days.

1. Is this normal ? If server processes are running, probably same connection is getting used but still, so high value ? Will these values disappear only on next deployment (or when I restart services) ?
2. Is there some way on rails application level to fix this ? Even the mysql global wait timeout value is 8 hours, how is this possible that the threads are in sleep state from last 7 - 10 days ?
3. There was some really heavy query run 2 months ago due to which we saw a sharp drop of about 1 GB. Can that memory ever be recovered without database restart ? Application restart is possible (in parts).

Comment: Are you intent to let everyone guess that you are using a t2.micro RDS instances?

Comment: @mootmoot, it's a r3.2xl instance. 
BTW, t2.micro has just 1GB RAM and in point 3, I am talking about 1GB sharp drop. Considering t2.micro for 'sharp 1G drop' could have been a production outage for anybody

Comment: Asking for instance type is just a hint of insufficient information. Anyway, I suggest  i. Do a EXPLAIN PLAN on the query you made,  diagnose it and/or post any issues you face  ii. always provide adequate info e.g. spec, tuning parameter,etc  before you ask performance questions. iii. move database question to https://dba.stackexchange.com/  , this is true even for RDS.